# How to specify realm creation to be overwritten on keycloak startup

Tags: docker, keycloak

Unable to add custom realm (say sso) using the following command as it always skips since it finds the master realm, is there a better way to overwrite and how do I specify that configuration

```
docker run --name keycloak_unoptimized -p 8080:8080 \
        -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=change_me \
        -v /path/to/realm/data:/opt/keycloak/data/import \
        quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest \
        start-dev --import-realm
```